# Print after file read callback

Tags: javascript, node.js

Make the last console.log the one with ---- print after all files have been read.

```
fs.readdir(inputFolder, function(err, list) {
    list.forEach(function(file){
        console.log('# ' + file + ' --> ' + folder);
    });    
});

console.log('--------------------------------------------------------');
```

Comment: Put that line after `list.forEach` not after `fs.readdir`

Comment: i though for each was a callback ;(

Comment: post this as the answer

Comment: Can I post it , lol , just kidding

Comment: well, @RayonDabre chose to not post the solution but a rather irritating explantion (I didn't understand it, too - why did you come up with the async package?). So I explained why his code doesn't work and provided the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `forEach` does the synchronous operation and `fs.readdir` is asynchronous hence  `console.log('--------------------------------------------------------');` will execute right after `fs.readdir`.

To print it after all the iterations of `list`, put your log statement after `list.forEach` not after `fs.readdir`

Comment: what do u mean by "in this case"

Comment: which means the default behaviour it's sync

Comment: I think what @RayonDabre is trying to explain is this: readdir is async, forEach is sync. And because forEach is sync, code after it will process only if forEach has finished. And that in turn means, your line should be *inside* readdir but *after* list.forEach to let the files be printed first.

Comment: And btw: the solution to that would be what I've posted as answer.

Comment: **No!** `forEach` is synchronous in nature. I need to update my answer!

Comment: That **No!** was directed towards @aWebDeveloper, right?

Answer (score 0):

```
fs.readdir(inputFolder, function(err, list) {
    list.forEach(function(file){
        console.log('# ' + file + ' --> ' + folder);
    });
    console.log('--------------------------------------------------------      ');   
});
```

`fs.readdir` is asynchronous. That means, code after that call will continue to run even though readdir is not finished.
You could use [readdirSync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdirsync_path) to run it synchronously but that would be a bad choice if there's also another solution. You always want asynchronous in js because that's what makes js fast because nothing will block execution of code.
Putting the line in the readdir callback after each file has been printed, will solve your problem.